# Synonym for "Many-to-Many" relationship (relational databases)

Tags: php, database-design, oop, orm, relational-database

What's a synonym for a "many-to-many" relationship? I've finished writing an object-relational mapper but I'm still stumped as to what to name the function that adds that relation.

addParent() and addChild() seemed quite logical for the many-to-one/one-to-many and addSuperclass() for one-to-one inheritance, but addManyToMany() would sound quite unintuitive to an object-oriented programmer. addSibling() or addCousin() doesn't really make sense either.

Any suggestions? And before you dismiss this as a non-programming question, please remember that consistent naming schemes and encapsulation are pretty integral to programming :)

Comment: a Synonym for “Many-to-Many” relationship is 'poor db design'  ;-)

Comment: How so? I would assure you that Stack Overflow's Questions <=> Tags is a many-to-many relationship. I can't imagine doing a lot of things without a many-to-many, because CSV fields are quite inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `addFriend()`? Other options might be `addLinked()` or `addRelated()`.

Comment: Many to Many Relations are *related* to orgies, addRelated(me)! +1 x)

Answer (score 1):

In relational database terms the general case is called an Inclusion Dependency, ie: A is a subset of B, where A and B are projections on some (not necessarily distinct) relations. A "foreign key" is a special case of inclusion dependency where B is a candidate key.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP calls this a 'Has and belongs to many' association

http://book.cakephp.org/view/85/Saving-Related-Model-Data-HABTM

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was something that would be meaningful to someone who isn't familiar with relational databases but understands object-oriented concepts. Plus "addHasAndBelongsToMany()" is even more unwieldy to type than "addManyToMany()".

Answer (score 0):

How about `addList` or `addChildern` or `addParents` or `addParentsAndChildren`?

Answer (score 0):

in this example http://pastie.org/938704 wouldn't you just create a method called:

AddUserGame(User someUser, Game someGame)

Comment: Interesting idea, however going by the Questions <=> Tags example, a 'QuestionTag' doesn't seem to make much sense as an object in itself. If I was making a page to display questions, the Tags would be children of the Questions, while if I was making a page to display Tags, the Questions would be children of the Tags. I guess it's hard finding a way to describe two things that can both be children of each other!

Answer (score 0):

Tricky! there does not seem to be a generic term that fits "RelateXtoY()" is the best I can come up with.

However for any actual "real" data model there is usually an obvious "verb" which can be used. eg for a many to many relationship between say Country and Airline you could have a method AddRouteTo(CountryId,AirlineId)  or TravelledToUsing(CountryId,AirlineId).

Answer (score 0):

What about this line of thought:

- `connect(X, Y)`
- `link(X, Y)`
- `bind(X, Y)`

Not only is it hard to find names for this kind of relation for Object Oriented systems, it is also hard to model them too! **Objects tend to live in hierarchies...**

See if you can find a container for such a relationship - check what method names that library uses.